# Extract iOS default icons

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I extract iOS default icons, used in settings, for example? 
I googled that 6 years ago they were located at 
 `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs` 
But seems like folder doesn't contain any icons anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I think all these icons are actually `png` images and they are in different folders inside `Xcode.app`: some are in CoreServices, others in Applications.

I suggest to show contents of Xcode.app in Finder and then search for `png` files checking `"Xcode.app"`.

Here what I got...

[image]

Comment: Wow. Great! For some reason Xcode.app contains only homepod glyph, I hoped to find more devices like applewatch, iphones, that are ised in batteries widget.